# How to get window URL after redirect?

Tags: javascript

```
var win = window.open('http://example.com/login');

console.log(window.location.pathname); // /login
```

How to get pathname after /login page redirect me to other page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `win` not `window` to retrieve it.

```
console.log(win.location.pathname);
```

Please note that you can retrieve the path only after the redirection is completed. So I guess you can get the path data by using timer or some other events ( e.g. click ) like below:

```
<script>
var win = window.open('http://example.com/login');
function showChildURL(){
    alert(win.location.href);
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:showChildURL();">showChildURL</a>
```

---

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script language="javaScript">
      var win = window.open('1.html');
      function showChildURL(){
        alert(win.location.pathname);
      }
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:showChildURL();">showChildURL</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**1.html**

```
<html>
  <head>      
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='2.html'" />    
  </head>    
  <body> 
    <p>This page will be redirected to 2.html</p> 
  </body>  
</html>
```

**2.html**

```
<html>
  <body> 
  This is 2.html 
  </body>  
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achive is communication between browser tabs/windows. You'll have to use cookie or localStorage to notify your main window about redirected url. Take a look at [LocalConnection](https://github.com/jeremyharris/LocalConnection.js).